# How to use page controls in spritekit? (Programatically)

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, pagecontrol

I am creating a game and I want to include a page control (the three dots on the bottom of the screen - I would post a picture but I need more reputation!). This is so the user knows what page they are on while they are flicking through the scenes. 
I have created my game using SpriteKit and I was wondering if there is a way to add this programtically (without the use of story boards).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an iOS Game template Playground I was able to achieve this with the following code (first two lines are from the template, the rest is my addition):

```
// Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x:0 , y:0, width: 640, height: 480))

let pageControl = UIPageControl()
pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
pageControl.numberOfPages = 3
pageControl.currentPage = 1
sceneView.addSubview(pageControl)

// Centre the control left-to-right
pageControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sceneView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
// Place the control 20 points up from the bottom edge
pageControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sceneView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
```

To be notified of interaction with the `UIPageControl`, register a handler for the event:

```
pageControl.addTarget(thing, action: #selector(Thing.handlePagingEvent), for: .valueChanged)
```

(Where `thing` is of type `Thing` - your app structure will determine which object that should logically be)

This assumes you have a single `SKView` in which you present one of three `SKScene`s. If you actually have a `UIScrollView` containing three `SKView`s, then look to `UIScrollView.indicatorStyle` instead.